# Data stucture for large binary data manipulation

Tags: c++11, bit, genetics

Hello fellow programmers,

I am working on a genetic project where the speed efficiency is crucial. I have essentially a lot of binary data to process. I work in c++11. I have two functions that needs to be optimized.

First, I need to be able to use binary operators between four binary strings and then check if all the bits are all zeros.

i.e. (bitV1 & (bitV2^bitV3)| bitV4) == 0..0

Second, I sometimes need to flip certain bits at certain location.

My problem is that bitset need to know the size at compile time, and I don’t know that size at compile time only at execution. And vector doesn’t seem to work with binary operators. I could translate my data in chars/string or int arrays and then use the bitwises operators on those but the code is not going to be pretty.

Does somebody know an efficient and simple way to do this?

Here is an MWE:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<bitset>
#include<vector>


int main() {
// I dont know the sizes for the sequences at compile time.
//std::bitset<intFromFile> firstBitset ("0011"); // doesnt compile

std::bitset<4> firstBitset ("0011");
std::bitset<4> secondBitset ("0101");
std::bitset<4> resultBitset = firstBitset &secondBitset;
std::cout << resultBitset; //OK

std::vector<bool> firstVector  {0,0,1,1};
std::vector<bool> secondVector {0,1,0,1};
//std::vector<bool> result = firstVector^secondVector; //ERROR
std::vector<bool> result {0,0,0,1}; //  OK

for (unsigned short int i = 0 ; i < result.size(); ++i){
    std::cout << result.at(i);
}
std::cout << std::endl;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: in between thousands and millions.

Comment: If you want it simple, one of the ways is to use `std::valarray<uint64_t>` then you can use bitwise operators directly (example https://ideone.com/8erLrQ). If you want it efficient then I would implement the operation in C and SIMD intrinsics and use `std::vector` as container, and use `boost::alignment::aligned_allocator` rather than the default allocator.

Comment: I will use Intel Threading Building Blocks to parallelize computation. I want speed efficiency so you sugest using std::vector of what ? Why is the purpose of aligned allocator?

Comment: It depends on how you want to vectorize the operations. If you want to use the default operators then you can use `uint64_t` or `__int128` which are widely available on a few popular compilers. Basically you want the widest unsigned integer type that supports bitwise operators. However if you decide to write the operations without using bitwise operators, then all you need from std::vector is as a container, then type  doesn't matter much. Allocator is to help ensure the storage is aligned to a certain boundary so that SIMD code is easier to write and run faster.

Comment: However all above is using the SIMD model. You can also consider multi threading model, using OpenMP or something. SIMD and multi threading are pretty much independent. The best approach is probably `std::valarray<uint64_t>` and OpenMP first and leave the vectorization to the compiler. If OpenMP does not suffice, then go to manually vectoring the code.